# Prepend a zero to the times in my select tag

Tags: jquery

I want to prepend a zero to the times in my select tag where there is a single digit whose values will be inserted into mysql via php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $select = $("#hr-on");
    for (i=1;i<=23;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
        var $select = $("#min-on");
    for (i=0;i<=59;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }        
});
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raistlin_Majere/dkpq238f/4/)

Comment: `val((i >1) ? '0' + i : i)` as well as inside html?

Comment: You're right [edited]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop check for the `value` of `i` and if less than `10` prepend with `0` else keep it as it is.

```
for (i=0;i<=59;i++){
     if(i<10)
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val("0"+i).html("0"+i))
     else
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dkpq238f/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
for (i=1;i<=23;i++){
    var num =  ((""+i).length == 1) ? "0" + i : i;
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(num))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient method but you could add a zero to all values and then take a substring of the last two characters -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var addZero = function (val) {
    var textVal = "0" + val;
    return textVal.substring(textVal.length - 2);
  }
  var $select = $("#hr-on");
  var val;
  for (i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(addZero(i)).html(addZero(i)))
  }
  var $select = $("#min-on");
  for (i = 0; i <= 59; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(addZero(i)).html(addZero(i)))
  }
  var $select = $("#hr-off");
  for (i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(addZero(i)).html(addZero(i)))
  }
  var $select = $("#min-off");
  for (i = 0; i <= 59; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(addZero(i)).html(addZero(i)))
  }
});
```

A forked version of your Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vd32h9uv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `if{...}else{...}` statement.

```
if(i<10){
  $select.append($('<option></option>').val("f5a5a608"+i).html("0"+i))
}
else{
  $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
}
```

[**DEMO on JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/2xjkd2Lm/)